# Why does my network adapter not appear in WinXP Device manager?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, network-adapter

I'm sure My IBM thinkpad has a network adapter as I used it for many years. However, the last time I used it is approximately 8 years ago. I do not know if something touched it or did something to it so that now I could not use that network adapter.

Going to Device Manager, I see no Network Adapter, please see the image
 [image: Windows Device Manager]

So, what should I do to get my network adapter back up and running?

Comment: ethernet controller = network adapter

Comment: why it got yellow and what should i do to fix it?

Comment: because the driver is not installed

Comment: It looks like you have some pretty basic drivers missing. You're going to have to find out what the chipset is, then go get the most basic driver setups. If it's VIA, your advantage is they all come in one package...

Comment: i fixed, thax u